# how to view memory used by operating system and web server in hyper v

Tags: hyper-v, centos7, hyper-v-server-2012, operating-system

I have a situation where i need to view memory and disk space used by operating systems (windows2012r2 and centos) and web servers (IIS(windows2012r2) and apache(centos)), both of them made as a virtual servers in hyper v.

Comment: "I am kind of new to this" does not excust a request basically for learning material, which is off topic. If you need ad admin to do your work, hire one.

Comment: uh okay I guess. I am just a student so i thought these sites are suppose to help but okay!

Comment: We can help, if you have a problem or a particular thing you need to know. But we can't teach you how to manage a server, that's beyond the scope of this website.

Comment: ah okay! its actually a part of assignment to be honest, to just write about these details.

Comment: Then learn up on powershell. Also define requirements - what you mean "by os and web server in hyper-v" - ihyper-v does not distinguish what in a vm uses memory.

Comment: so it seems, so i just have mentioned total memory, committed memory and have also came across memory consumption in IIS (in server manager), so i have just included these screen shots in my assignment for windows 2012, as for centos there were no such details available , so i just used the screen shots of commands free -h and df -h. i ought to discuss it with my teacher after he returns assignment. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try to enable VM Monitoring - `Enable-VMResourceMetering` (via PowerShell) and use `Measure-VM` cmdlet to gather information from the VM itself, however, the disk space usage is not showing here, just an entire VHDX size - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/measure-vm?view=win10-ps and this - http://www.itprotoday.com/virtualization/q-how-do-i-enable-and-view-windows-server-2012-hyper-v-metric-information

Comment: i've read the article you shared! but just to be expected, it just gives info about whole disk drive and RAM. i may be interpreting it wrong but question is actually this:"How much memory and disk space does each of your Virtual Machine Operating Systems use and how much memory do your Webservers use?" clearly enough i wasn't able to pinpoint memory and disk space for os and webserver separately. Regardless, thank you for sharing those blogs Mr. Raspberry!